# How to remove extra space in empty tag using XSLT in BizTalk

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, biztalk

I use Visual Studio XSLT processor in BizTalk Project.

In XSLT `<tag/> or <tag></tag>`
creates output with extra space on the end like this `<tag />`

When select gives no results: `<tag><xsl:value-of select="s0:tag/text()"/></tag>` gives me `<tag/>` and this is OK.

So there is extra space when using non-select version. This extra space makes the difference when encoding this XML to JSON.

How to get rid of this extra space with a more elegant approach than selecting an empty tag?

Comment: `<tag/>` is exactly the same thing as `<tag />`.  I don't know if you can control the way your processor serializes the output tree. In any case, if it makes a difference to your target application, then it's the target application that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Logically yes but, this extra space makes the difference when encoding this XML to JSON and this encoder is embedded in Biztalk Engine so I believe it should be manageable

Comment: In what way is `<tag/>` encoded in JSON, how is the encoding for `<tag />` different? And which is the result you want? I guess `{ "tag" : null }` versus `{ "tag" : "" }` might be the issue but you haven't really explained which issue exactly arises.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Good guess its { "tag" : null } versus { "tag" : "" }

Comment: Is the encoding to JSON done by your own code? Or some API? Does it have any options how to map empty XML elements to JSON you can configure?

Comment: No - its done by JSON encoder embedded in Biztalk engine. I could use mine but its more complex than just use this select-like method

Comment: Which behaviour are you getting?  Are you getting null when you expect "" or expect "" and get null?  See this blog for a workaround  https://www.connected-pawns.com/2016/01/04/rest-json-christmas-puzzle-work-around/  This beviour has varied depending on which JSON library BizTalk used

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Thank You, this is what I suspected. I wish to have consistent behaviour of Biztalk JSON encoder